# I want to know how to delete a value inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a hard time with my delContact method because I want to delete the object which is similar to delVar but I don't know how to I've tried all = None or del all. but when I a call the show method/function after the delContact(), the value that I wanted to delete still shows

```
class Phonebook:

    def __init__(self,name,type,email,phone):

        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

        print('Adding {} as a Contact with an email of {} and a phone number of {}'.format(self.name,self.email,self.phone))

    def tell(self):

        print('Name: {} | Type: {} | Email: {} | Phone: {}'.format(self.name,self.type,self.email,self.phone))

    def retName(self):

        return  self.name

All = []

def addContact():
    name = input('Enter your the name please: ')
    type = input('Enter the type of the Contact Please: ')
    email = input('Enter the the email of the Contact Please: ')
    phone = input('Enter the Phone number of the Contact Please: ')

    merge = Phonebook(name,type,email,phone)

    All.append(merge)

def show():

    for all in All:
        all.tell()

def delContact():

    show()

    delVar = input('Enter the name you want to delete: ')

    for all in All:

        if all.retName() == delVar:
            print(all.retName())
            all = ''
        else:
            continue



addContact()
addContact()
show()
delContact()
show()
```

Comment: you forgot adding `self` as default argument to your methods. Also create an object and then call methods. You are having a constructor for no reason if you don't intend your methods to be used against an instance

Comment: @PrakashPalnati What are you talking about exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
for all in All:
    if all.retName() == delVar:
        print(all.retName())
        all = ''
```

you are not deleting anything, you are just rebinding the local name `all` to the empty string. To delete the item from the list, you would have to use `All.remove(item)`:

```
for all in All:
    if all.retName() == delVar:
        All.remove(all)
        break
```

Note that if you have more than one item with the same name, this will only remove the first one...

Also note that modifying a list you're iterating upon can lead to unexpected results. It's safe in this case since we immediatly break out of the loop but it's usually something to avoid.

Another solution which is safer and will remove **all** matching items is to filter out the list and replace the original with the result:

```
All[:] = [item for item in All if item.name != delVar]
```

Oh and yes too, your `retName` method is totally useless, `name` is a public attribute of your class.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much. How about if I want to edit something in my Contact list?